# Does $y= x^3$ have a horizontal asymptote at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Does the function $f(x)=x^3$ have a horizontal asymptote at $x=0$?

I know that the derivative of $f(x)$ approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$, so does that mean $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote?

Comment: You mean tangent, not asymptote.

Comment: Why don't you start with the definition of an "asymptote" first? Also look up definitions of "stationary point" and "point of inflection".

Comment: A horizontal asymptote is when the curve approaches $y= c;$ a constant, or equivalently if $f'(x)\to 0$ *as $x\to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$*.  As you are looking at $x\to 0$ and you are *not* looking at $x\to \infty$ this is *not* a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: @flea that is not equivalent. The function $f(x) = \frac{\sin\left(x^2\right)}{x}$ has a horizontal asymptote of $x = 0$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)$ is not $0$; the limit does not exist. Also, for the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = 0$, but $\sqrt{x}$ has no horizontal asymptote. If a function has a horizontal asymptote and the limit of the derivative exists, then that limit must be 0, but there's no guarantee of existence, and the converse is false.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a matter of definition - a horizontal asymptote is not any point where the derivative is zero. Instead, we say a function has a horizontal asymptote of $y = c$ if $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = c$ or $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = c$. Visually, this looks like $f(x)$ "flattening out" and approaching the line $y = c$ as you go off to the right or the left. The critical part of this is that it's a limit towards infinity, not towards a specific point.

A point where the derivative is zero is known as a critical point. On $f(x) = x^3$, the critical point at $x = 0$ is known as a saddle point, since it's neither a local minimum nor a local maximum.